# Concurrent update and read for an Read-Write caching strategy leads to inconsistency of Data in L2 cache

Tags: hazelcast, softlock

I am facing issues for integration of Hazelcast(Version 3.3) L2 cache in my Application. Following are the scenarios;

- First scenario: There is a session created with CacheMode set to Normal. CacheConcurrencyStrategy is READ_WRITE for the entity which I want to cache. Now, I am loading this entity for the first time, so it will load from database and put the same in the cache also. Later I am updating the entity with the value lets say name from 'OldName' to 'NewName'. It is updating name into database, evicting the Entity from L2 and updating the time stamp into the L2 cache however it is not loading the entity back with latest value in L2. The question is shouldn't the session have put the Entity with Updated value into L2 back after updating it into database? Am I missing some configuration here?
- Second Scenario: There are two different sessions lets say S1 and S2 running with the same configuration (CacheMode set to Normal). S1 loaded the entity, put it in the L2 and updated the value (name from 'OldName' to 'NewName'). It evicts the entity from L2 and tried to update the value in the database. But between flush() and Commit(), the second session S2 tried to get the entity. Because the S1 had evicted it from L2 and has aquire the SoftLock on the Entity, S2 is loading it from the database, obviously it will load old values(name="OldName") with old version, because S1 has not yet committed into Database. Now when S1 commits the new value(name="NewName") in database and releases the SoftLock on the Entity, S2 will put the entity into L2. Here the L2 and database are not in sync, because in Database name is "NewName" with version 1 and L2 it is "OldName" with version 0.
- Third scenario: In continuation with the second scenario, if S2 or any other new sessions try to update the entity, those will get Concurrency exception as there is version mismatch.

Definitely there has to be some solution to these scenarios provided (as these are very basic scenarios), which I am not able to find out. Please help me with this.

Comment: I know my question might also be buried somewhere within your question, but it looks a night terror. I would rather suffer the unanswered than suffer reading through this.